# Nodejs mysql query returning strange results instead of records

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql2 module for nodejs async await.
my query setup is following

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

static async insert (values_array){

  const connection =await mysql.createConnection({
                    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
                    password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
                    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
                    Promise: bluebird
                });
                connection.on('error', function (err) {
                    error = err;
                    console.log('ERROR => ' + err);
                });
                await connection.connect()
                var table=this.table_name

                try {
                    const query = "SELECT * FROM `" + table + "` WHERE `status` = 'pending'";
                    const rows = await connection.query(query);
                    console.log( rows);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('ERROR => ' + err);

                } finally {
                    connection.end();
                }

}
```

Here I am expecting the variable row to be containing the result in a row or object which I can use via loops or return as JSON to the frontend. But what I get is following

```
[
  [],
  [
    ColumnDefinition {
      _buf: <Buffer 01 00 00 01 08 2c 00 00 02 03 64 65 66 08 77 61 6c 6c 65 74 64 62 05 75 73 65 72 73 05 75 73 65 72 73 02 69 64 02 69 64 0c 3f 00 14 00 00 00 08 0
3 42 ... 433 more bytes>,
      _clientEncoding: 'utf8',
      _catalogLength: 3,
      _catalogStart: 10,
      _schemaLength: 8,
      _schemaStart: 14,
      _tableLength: 5,
      _tableStart: 23,
      _orgTableLength: 5,
      _orgTableStart: 29,
      _orgNameLength: 2,
      _orgNameStart: 38,
      characterSet: 63,
      encoding: 'binary',
      name: 'id',
      columnLength: 20,
      columnType: 8,
      flags: 16899,
      decimals: 0
    },
.....
```

There are many column definition objects in the returned array. I searched over google but found nothing. Or I just did not know how to search over google.

How to records from the database?.

NOTE: same happens with the MySQL node module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `query` function from `mysql2` returns an array of two arrays, rows & fields (aka columns). What you're seeing is actually an empty result set (notice how the first array is empty) and then a long list of column definitions, which aren't useful for you. Instead, try destructuring the returned array to get just what you need:

```
const [rows] = await connection.query(query);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my issue and saved a lot of my time. Noob me was trying to figure this out for 2 days.

Comment: @Nadir glad I could help! As a tip, when in doubt, go back to the docs and look to see if any examples do what you want to do -- and then look for what you're doing differently. In this case, https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-promise-wrapper was the example I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no issue with code but there might be a query issue because you have written query within double quotes(").

Your Query

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM `" + table + "` WHERE `status` = 'pending'";
```

I suggest you should replace with **backtick**

```
 const query = `SELECT * FROM  ${table}  WHERE status = 'pending' `;
```

Note: make sure data is present in the Database against the query